# Get the most near value mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

PRICE

```
id   price   date
1     50     20130716
2     30     20130717
```

TVA

```
id    val      start      end
1      7     20080101   20103112
2      8     20110101
```

MARGIN

```
id    qty    marg
1     500     25
2     600     20
3     800     15
4     1000    13
5     1250    11
...
```

Now I have this query which doesn't works:

```
$quantity = '557';

$link->query("
       SELECT (
              (price+marg)*((val+100)/100)
              )
       FROM PRICE
         JOIN TVA
         JOIN MARGIN
       WHERE date = '20130717' 
             AND end = ''
             AND qty = '$quantity'
");
```

The problem is that there isn't a `qty = '557'` on the table.
What I'd like to do is to select the most near quantity to (in this case) '557'.

So if:

`$quantity = '557'` the query should select `600`

`$quantity = '701'` the query should select `800`

`$quantity = '1238'` the query should select `1250`

etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: All your examples show rounding "up" to the next quantity... presumably you would want to round "down" if it was closer?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634725/select-closest-numerical-value-with-mysql-query

Answer (score 1):

If you put it into a procedure, you can use something like this (sort-of pseudocode):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pDoStuff(@target INTEGER)
AS

    DELCARE @qty INTEGER

    -- Get closest qty
    @qty = SELECT TOP 1 qty
            FROM table
            ORDER BY ABS(@target - qty) ASC


    -- use that "actual" qty in your query
    SELECT  ((price+marg)*((val+100)/100)
    FROM    price
    JOIN    TVA
    JOIN    MARGIN
    WHERE   date = 'thedate'
    AND     end = ''
    AND     qty = @qty

GO
```

The syntax is incorrect, but it gives you an idea.  This will allow you to select ALL rows from your original query with the closest quantity value.  Most of the other answers here will limit your final results to one row (which may or may not be what you actually want).

Comment: Thank you! Now the problem is to correct the syntax for mySQL... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
AND `qty` <= $quantity
ORDER BY `qty` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value bigger than yours, ordered ascending and limit to 1 result. so you can firt value bigger or equal yours

```
  SELECT (
              (price+marg)*((val+100)/100)
              )
       FROM PRICE
         JOIN TVA
         JOIN MARGIN
       WHERE date = '20130717' 
             AND end = ''
             AND qty >= '$quantity'
ORDER BY qty ASC LIMIT 1
```

With same method you can get value lower than your number and see which one is closer to your qty