# MySQL returning rows which are closest in value to a specific number

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have a table in my database similar to the one below:

```
id  |   name    |   score
==========================
...     ...         ...
44      Bob         89
45      Jane        567
46      Andrew      22
...     ...         ...
```

`score` will always be a positive integer. Let's say I want to return the 5 users who have scores which are *closest* to Jane. How would I do this using SQL (or Eloquent), assuming 5 is a variable?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1634745/1374307).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by abs(score - (select score from your_table where name = 'Jane'))
limit 5
```

Comment: I had to wrap the `score` values with `CAST(score as SIGNED)` statements, but this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: How can I then sort the closest values by score? Doing `order by abs(score - (select score from your_table where name = 'Jane')), score asc` doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can add other sort criterias: `order by abs(...) asc, score desc` for instance

Comment: That doesn't work. What I want is to select the 5 rows which are closest in value, then sort them by their value.

Comment: `select * from (select * from your_table
order by abs(score - (select score from your_table where name = 'Jane'))
limit 5) tmp order by score`