# How to get closest SUMMED mySQL value to an existing value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Two tables in MySQL database...

- players (playerid, teamid, position, firstname, lastname)
- stats (statsid, playerid, points, year)

Let's say my baseline player has 83 points (i.e. the "existing value").

I want to find the ONE player from the database that has the closest point total to 83.

NOTE: This existing question is similar but doesn't involve SUMMING:  [Select closest numerical value with MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634725/select-closest-numerical-value-with-mysql-query)

So this general method would work...

```
select   points,
         abs(points - 83) as distance_from_test
from     stats
order by distance_from_test
limit 1
```

But my issue is that there are multiple "points" entries for each player in a same year. So I want to SUM all point totals for each player first and THEN find the closest total to 83.  This doesn't work, but this is basically what I want to do...

```
select   SUM(points) as totalpoints,
         abs(totalpoints - 83) as distance_from_test
from     stats
order by distance_from_test
limit 1
```

When I try that I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)" so I'm assuming maybe you can't do this type of summing along with the abs math function.  Can anyone confirm/deny that and point me in a smarter direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to the error, you're using sum without a `group by` which means you're only going to get one row regardless of the limit.

Comment: The error you are showing is a PHP error, put in the PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY player` and you must use the calculation instead of the alias:

```
select   player,
         SUM(points) as totalpoints,
         abs(SUM(points) - 83) as distance_from_test
from     stats
GROUP BY player
order by distance_from_test
limit 1
```